rio.to_raster method is not working (rioxarray package)
I want to export a data cube (hyperspectral data) to a .tif file using the rio.to_raster module, which should be inside the rioxarray package.
But when I try to recall the module (rio.to_raster) it seems that doesn't exist, even if I installed and imported the rioxarray package.
So I imported all the libraries I need:
#Importing libraries
import rioxarray as riox
import numpy as np

Then, trying to do this:
M3_hull_export=M3_hull.copy()
M3_hull_export.data[M3_hull_export.data==0]=np.nan
M3_hull_export.rio.to_raster(f'{path_results}/{target}_conremoved_CH.tif') #Uncomment if you want to export the continuum-removed file

Obtaining this error:
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File rasterio\\_io.pyx:1488, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__()

File rasterio\\_err.pyx:221, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: Attempt to create new tiff file '/D:/PhD_CISAS/M3_Marius_conremoved_CH.tif' failed: No error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RasterioIOError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 5
      3 M3_hull_export=M3_hull.copy()
      4 M3_hull_export.data[M3_hull_export.data==0]=np.nan
----> 5 M3_hull_export.rio.to_raster(f'{path_results}/{target}_conremoved_CH.tif')

File c:\Users\melch\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py:1133, in RasterArray.to_raster(self, raster_path, driver, dtype, tags, windowed, recalc_transform, lock, compute, **profile_kwargs)
   1114 out_profile = {
   1115     key: value
   1116     for key, value in out_profile.items()
   (...)
   1127     )
   1128 }
   1129 rio_nodata = (
   1130     self.encoded_nodata if self.encoded_nodata is not None else self.nodata
...
    344     )

File rasterio\\_io.pyx:1493, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__()

RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file '/D:/PhD_CISAS/M3_Marius_conremoved_CH.tif' failed: No error


I try to write this line to know more details:
import sys
print(riox.rio.to_raster.__file__)
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 5
      1 #import sys
      2 #print(MoonIndex.preparation.__file__)
      4 import sys
----> 5 print(riox.rio.to_raster.__file__)

AttributeError: module 'rioxarray' has no attribute 'rio'

I don't know what to do to solve this problem, I thank in advance whoever will answer this question.
